# (double proxy) node js create proxy server behind corporate proxy using node-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, double, node-http-proxy

I have anodejs application that uses node-http-proxy to create a proxy to send the incoming requests for example: http://**localhost**/api/login to https://**server1**/api/login. here is the code used :

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

self.routes['/api/*'] = function(req, res) {
        proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, 
        {
            target: "https://server1",
            changeOrigin: true
        });
    };
```

This is working just fine in my machine.
Now when i deploy this on a server, i get error:

{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }

> **The problem is that there is another proxy (corporate proxy called: localProxy) between myserver and server1.**

I don't know where to set the localProxy in my code above. and where to set the server1 url?

and is there is a way to use node-http-proxy in this case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer for me was stop using proxy module and make the proxy operation manually.

please find code below:

```
self.app.all('/blabla/*',function(req,res) {
    console.log("inside /blabla request");


  if(req.method=="GET"){
     console.log(req.url);
     var headers = {

        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': req.body.length ,
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
      };



    request({
      url: "http://YOUR_EXTERNAL_SERVER"+req.url,
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: true,
      maxRedirects: 10,
      headers: headers
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("error " +error + " body "+ body);
            if(!error ) console.log(response.statusCode);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              if(body){    
                var ob=JSON.parse(body);
                res.send(body);
              }
            }
            else if (!error){
              console.log(" response.statusCode "+ response.statusCode);
                res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
            }
            else {
                res.status(500).send(error);
            }    
    });
  }
  }
```